# Why is all of this needed for JSON?

Tags: c#, json

I am learning JSON and I have gotten it to work, but I am wanting to know WHY it works and how it works. I am confused as to why some lines are needed and what they do.

Below is my main cs and my `Person` class: I am under the impression that I am making `JSONstring` equal to the content of JSON.json. If that is the case, why can I not just `Writeline JSONstring` and add `\n` inside of there to separate lines?

From what I gather is that `Console.WriteLine(p1);` outputs `p1` which is equal to the deserialized JSON. I am not exactly sure why the other code is needed.

```
// Make JSONstring = to the text in JSON.json
String JSONstring = File.ReadAllText("JSON.json");

JavaScriptSerializer ser = new JavaScriptSerializer();
Person p1 = ser.Deserialize<Person>(JSONstring);
Console.WriteLine(p1);
Console.ReadLine();

class Person
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public int age { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return string.Format("Name: {0} \nAge: {1}", name, age);
    }
}
```

Comment: How would you know exactly where to separate the lines? More realistically, the goal of your project will not be simply to reformat the JSON, but to use the actual values. For that to work, you do need to deserialize it...

Comment: So you created a project to practice working with JSON, and in that project you deserialize a string and print out the values, and you're wondering why you didn't just print out the original string instead of deserializing it?  Was it not, as you said, to practice working with JSON?  If that's not it, then that's a question only you can answer.

Comment: p1 is not the deserialized JSON.  It is the return result of the `ToString()` method.  If that happens to be JSON, well, OK.  But it could be anything at all.

Comment: @RobertHarvey "p1 is not the deserialized JSON" It sure looks like it is to me... `Person p1 = ser.Deserialize<Person>(JSONstring);` Am I missing something?

Comment: @Servy: `Console.WriteLine(p1)` calls the `ToString()` method on object `p1`.  What that method returns isn't even valid JSON.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Yes.  The result of printing out `p1` to the console isn't necessarily serialized JSON (it could be whatever `ToString` defines, as you've said), but `p1` is absolutely the result of deserializing some JSON.

Comment: @Servy: Don't get pedantic on me.  I'm refuting the OP's assertion that "From what I gather is that Console.WriteLine(p1);
outputs p1 which is equal to the deserialized Json."

Comment: The default behavior of `ToString()` is to return the fully qualified name of the object, unless `ToString()` is overriden in that object to return something else.

Comment: @Tim: Which it is in the example.

Comment: @RobertHarvey - Ah, didn't see that.

Comment: @RobertHarvey You're being pedantic on the OP, trying to correct a statement that he made.  The OP's statement is correct (`p1` is indeed deserialized JSON), and you're pedantic correction of his statement isn't.  Why blame me for a pedantic correction of your pedantic correction of the OP?

Comment: @Servy: The output of the `ToString()` method is not the deserialized JSON.  It's not even JSON.

Comment: The reason for "all of that" is so that people don't have to write a custom `ToString()` implementation for all of their classes. They just run `JavaScriptSerializer.Serialize(person)` and know that someone else can run `JavaScriptSerializer.Deserialize<Person>(json)` and get the same data.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Correct.  `p1` is deserialized JSON, `p1.ToString()` is a custom string representation of that in-memory object.  Since the question states, "`p1` is deserialized JSON", it's correct.  If it said something like, "printing out `p1` to the console prints out JSON" then that would be wrong.

Comment: @Servy: I see how you're parsing the OP's sentence, but his confusion is almost certainly about what the `Console.WriteLine` statement is doing, not about the nature of object `p1`.  Not everyone writes as precise English as you do, and the language is ambiguous anyway.

Comment: @RobertHarvey All I ever got that he failed to understand was why you'd bother doing any of this, which didn't really make sense (hence my VTC).  I didn't really see anything that lead me to believe he didn't understand why the console output was what it is.  He never indicated anywhere that he was expecting the output to be something different than what it was.  (Of course, he also didn't demonstrate that he *does* understand it either, hence the lack of clarity in the question.)

Comment: @Servy: Well, the OP's confusion pivots on the statement "From what I gather is that Console.WriteLine(p1); outputs p1 which is equal to the deserialized JSON. I am not exactly sure why the other code is needed."  So until you resolve the first quandary, there's not much point in discussing the second.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Console.WriteLine(p1)
```

is not displaying JSON.  In effect, it calls the `ToString()` method on `p1`:

```
return string.Format("Name: {0} \nAge: {1}", name, age);
```

and outputs the result to the console.  `ToString()` can return anything you wish.

As to your original question, the purpose of such a serialization is to *save the state of an object to a text-based, human-readable form,* and then create an object later having that same state.  The `ToString` method doesn't have much to do with that, other than to give you a convenient way of viewing the state.

The "state" is the value of the member variables `name`and `age`, in your example.

Comment: Thank you, so it is less for the use in my example, and more for being able to use them when I actually need to do more in-dept things with the Json?

Comment: I don't understand what you just asked.  Use specific terms, like `ToString` or "state."

Comment: I was trying to state that in the structure of the code, a lot of it is a framework for more complicated use than simply outputting a console line.  This may be why it appears to me to be "Excess". I just simply do not have anything complicated enough to actually put the code to work.

Comment: JSON is useful for tons of things, and serializable objects make it very convenient to use, because you don't have to write a custom parser for each unique JSON object.